# Expo application on iOS crashes when uploading video to Firebase Storage. Works on android, just not iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, react-native, expo

I am trying to upload a video to firebase storage on iOS. Android works just fine. Here is the code causing it (there are comments in the code to show when it crashes). Also, I am using my own iPhone to test this, not a simulator.

```
export const mediaUpload = async (imageObject) => {
  // getting blob from a local file a user uploads from ImagePicker
  const blob = await fetch(imageObject[0].uri);
  const blobObject = await blob.blob();

  // creating reference path in storage
  const fileRef = ref(storage, `${auth.currentUser.uid}/videos/${uuid.v4()}`);
  // ----- no crash so far... -------

  // this is the issue line
  const attemptToUpload = await uploadBytes(fileRef, blobObject);
  // ------> APP CRASHES
}
```

On Android, this works with both images and videos. On iOS, images work but videos will crash the app completely. The blob type is video/quicktime. Why does uploadBytes method crash the app?

EDIT: The answer was that Firebase v9 seems to not be compatible with Expo on dealing with video uploads to storage 100%. Even android hangs on video uploads without any error message I found out. The way I solved this was to go back to version Firebase 8.10.0. This works 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this approach and works well on iOS 15.

```
 const videoRef = firebase.storage().ref("video/filename");

  const metadata = { contentType: "video/mp4" };

  const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };

    xhr.ontimeout = function (e) {
      // XMLHttpRequest timed out. Do something here.

      console.log(e);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      console.log(e);

      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", fileUri, true);
    xhr.timeout = 1000 * 60;
    xhr.send(null);
  });


  var uploadTask = videoRef.put(blob, metadata);

 

  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {
      // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
      // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
      const progress = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes;

    

      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
          console.log("Upload is paused");
          break;
        case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
          console.log("Upload is running");
          break;
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);

      // Handle unsuccessful uploads
      blob.close();
    },
    () => {
      // Handle successful uploads on complete
      // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
      uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {


console.log("Video file save at:",downloadURL)
       
      });
      blob.close();
    }
  );
```

Comment: So I just tried this in my code and one difference is I'm using firebase v9. But when I use uploadBytesResumable() ( which is just the new .put() ), the app crashes at random percentages in the progress of the upload.

Comment: V9 is new some compatibility issue expected? How costly it's to switch to V8. V9 provides also has backward compatibility with V8. You can use V8 feature in V9.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat

Comment: I changed my version to 8.10 in a sample app and ran the code, works perfect. So basically firebase v9 and expo have to have some sort of compatibility issues as you've stated. Even android doesn't process the progress % sometimes. Wild... THANKS FRIEND!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, on firebase version 9.6.5, while uploading image, so i have used function uploadBytesResumable instead of uploadBytes, it works just fine, if it is urgent you can use that function for the time being, just a recommendation, for reference:-
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

I faced this issue in iOS 15 and 15 + only, rest below iOS 15 and in android apps uploadBytes is working fine.

When using XMLHttpRequest with uploadBytesResumable, first time image uploads smoothly on iOS 15.2 then, on uploading it on second time there is crash while uploading image. To avoid it use,

```
const img = await fetch(image_url);
const blob = await img.blob();
```

So if you face any issue while uploading image then use this approach, for creating blob file

if you need reference of code, i have answered another question here of image upload error(firestorage),
[React Native expo image picker upload image to firebase storage (v9) crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528896/react-native-expo-image-picker-upload-image-to-firebase-storage-v9-crash?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Using `uploadBytesResumable` worked for me. I use the firebase javascript sdk on expo react native 49. This was the log that I was getting when looking into the simulator logs when my app was crashing

`NSInvalidArgumentException: *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0] firebase`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a known issue on the `ios` platform when body is just a blob. I ran into the same problem a few weeks ago and I fixed it by sending it to my backend and then uploading to the service that requires it.

Comment: Well what is weird is if I save my code after I use ImagePicker to get the image, the image uploads fine, but if you try to upload the image again it breaks. I think something is happening with a promise that expo isn't catching.

Answer (score -1):

So, I spent like 10 hrs with the same problem. Solved with this:

```
const img = await fetch(image_url);
const blob = await img.blob()
const newFile = new File([blob], `${any_name_you_want}.jpeg`, {
         type: 'image/jpeg',
})
```

Then send this file instead of Blob